# Get a multiple UNION ALL query faster

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, union-all

I have an issue of performance with a query with multiple UNION ALL statements. I need to add (row by row) data from different tables into the same columns. The query need to be used to create a view in MySQL, so, here an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = usr 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW my_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
   column 1, 
   column 2, 
   column 3
FROM 
   table 1
WHERE 
   condition 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
   column 1, 
   column 2, 
   column 3
FROM 
   table 2
WHERE 
   condition 2
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 
   column 1, 
   column 2, 
   column 3
FROM 
   table 3
WHERE 
   condition 3
```

It seems pointless to do all the multiple UNION ALLs just to add (row by row) data from the same features (not just 3 columns as in the example, I have many more) coming from different tables because this is something that requires lots of resources from the DB, leading to "lost connection error during the query" due to the time it takes to run.

Is there any way to optimize this kind of query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mysql <> SQL server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Performance related questions require an execution plan as the query is not what determines performance.

Comment: Running a complex query leads to resource consumption, although it is not the only cause of performance, it is an important cause for improving the query design. My question is about optimization to improve performance in a DB.

Comment: Yes but SQL is a declarative language, you are telling the engine what data you want, not how to obtain the data, that's why we need to see the execution plan - to see what the engine actually did.

Comment: I don't have that information :/ I work with a group of data engineers who have designed this MySQL DB which I access through MySQL Workbench and they have told me that this type of queries to generate a view produces a "time out in execution"

Comment: Shown pattern allows only separate subqueries optimizations. The UNION itself cannot be optimized. If combined output is too huge then you may try to use stored procedure in which the subqueries are executed separately copying the outputs into temptable - this may decrease memory consumption.

Comment: Did the data engineers suggest an alternative? And did you actually test their assertion? And does code with a load of unions produce the desired outcome? And do all the tables have useful indexes in place?

Comment: Please provide realistic table and column names -- there may be clues on how to rearrange the data to make things more efficient.

Comment: Such as -- the tables should have been a single table in the first place.

Comment: @Akina - a recent optimization to `UNION ALL` was to eliminate the temp table.  It _map_ apply in this example, depending on how the View is used.  For example, tack on GROUP BY or ORDER BY, and the temp table is again required.

Comment: @RickJames *a recent optimization to UNION ALL was to eliminate the temp table* Sometimes it is better to create temptable explicitly from the same beginning then create it implicitly when all available memory is occupied. *For example, tack on GROUP BY or ORDER BY, and the temp table is again required.* ORDER BY over temptable - and one more temptable is required? I doubt. Filesort is not equal to the temptable usage.

Comment: @Akina - I guess I need to see a test case where an explicit temp table works better.  I don't know exactly what is meant by "temp table" in UNION; I would guess it is just like subqueries, etc in a complex SELECT.  For example, the latter will sort in RAM when practical.

Comment: I don't think MySQL's Optimizer has yet implemented the pushing WHERE clauses down into individual UNION pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION ALL` is the most performant way of concatenating result sets. (`UNION` is slower because it removes duplicates.)

Surely your timeout occurs when you *use* the view, not when you create it.

Your performance issue stems from one or more of the SELECT queries in your `UNION ALL` cascade being very slow.  You, or your "data engineer" colleagues, may need to create appropriate indexes on your `table 1`, `table 2`, `table 3` tables.

To figure this out, do these things.

- Read [Optimizing Queries With EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).
- Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE whateverTableName;`. Look at the output. It will show you the indexes.
- Run the SELECT queries using that same table prefixed with `EXPLAIN`. It will show you the indexes it used to satisfy the query.
- Ask another question here showing us the output from those two steps.

Or, it's possible your resultset from your big query is vast. There's no magic that can process millions of rows faster than O(n).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the ideas around this case. I'm still working on it, however, my first attempt was taking the selects in the union all cascade and try to make views apart for them. Then, I made a general view calling the others and the performance was improved. I'll keep trying another approaches and share my results here. The EXPLAIN provided in MySQL workbench was ideal to see the execution plan and performance of the SELECTs inside the query.